# Unity - Logic for saving and loading objects with both static and dynamic data

Tags: unity, architecture

I need help to get some structure for my save and load.

I am making a city builder, so I have Buildings thats need to be saved.

Each building has a lot of static Data, for example `name`, `description`, etc.

However it also has a lot of dynamic Data, for example `worldPosition`, `id`, etc.

My current structure looks like this:

On each Building `GameObject` I keep a reference to a `ScriptableObject` that stores all the static data.
I also store a reference to an `Object` that stores all the dynamic data.

This means I need 2 classes for storing Building data, which I already don't like (`BuildingStaticData` & `BuildingDynamicData`)

When I Save/Load my game I only need to store the Dynamic data, so for saving I just save the `DynamicData`.

For Loading I load the `DynamicData`, and `instantiate` a Building `GameObject` that is associated with it, then the `GameObject` has the reference to the `StaticData`.

While this works, I would prefer to have a structure where I only have a single class for `BuildingData`, but I also don't want to lose the power of a `ScriptableObject` where I can reference other Prefabs etc.

I need some help with this logic.

Comment: Isn't your "static data" just "building type" for your "dynamic data"? Can you put a "building type" variable for your dynamic data object. It should be a bit of a work but you would be getting rid of your "static data" object.

Comment: i'm facing a similar architecture issue in my game. What did you end up doing? I too don't want to lose the power of scriptable objects but have a similar mix of static/dynamic data